# Setting value to a 2d dynamic array array C

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have to make sure row and col is valid and I have to set the value of `im->pixels[row][col]` to `val` and return `IMG_OK`.
Otherwise, the array will be unmodified and return. I know the problem is on `img_result_t img_set()`, but I cannot figure it out.
I'm not being able to set the val to my array. While running `main()` the output I am getting is,

```
        Creating test_im by calling 'img_create(10, 10)'
        test_im created successfully.
    
        Testing img_set.
        Cannot set value at index 0
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct { 
    uint8_t** pixels;
    unsigned int rows;
    unsigned int cols;
} img_t;

/// A type for returning status codes 

typedef enum {
    IMG_OK,
    IMG_BADINPUT,
    IMG_BADARRAY,
    IMG_BADCOL,
    IMG_BADROW,
    IMG_NOTFOUND
} img_result_t;


img_t *img_create(unsigned int rows, unsigned int cols){

    img_t* arr = malloc(sizeof(img_t));
  if(arr == NULL) return arr;

  arr->rows = rows;
  arr->cols = cols;

  arr->pixels = malloc(rows * sizeof(*arr->pixels));
  if(arr->pixels == NULL){
    free(arr);
    return NULL;
  }
  for(unsigned int i = 0; i<arr->rows; i++){
        arr->pixels[i] = malloc(cols*sizeof(img_t));
        if(arr->pixels[i] == NULL){
          for(int j= 0; j < i; j++){
            free(arr->pixels[i]);
          }
          free(arr->pixels);
          free(arr);
          return NULL;
          
        }
      }return arr;
}

void img_destroy(img_t* im){

    if(im != NULL){
      for(unsigned int i = 0; i < im->rows; i++){
        free(im->pixels[i]);
      }
        free(im->pixels);
        free(im);
    }
}


img_result_t img_set(img_t* im, unsigned int row, unsigned int col, int val){
  
  if(im == NULL) return IMG_BADARRAY;

  im->rows = row;
  im->cols = col;
  
  unsigned int empty = 0;

  if(row <= empty){
    return IMG_BADROW;
  }
  if(col <= empty){
    return IMG_BADCOL;
  }
  im->pixels[row][col] = val;
  return val;

}

// helper function that prints the content of the img
void print_img(img_t* im) {
    if (im == NULL) {
        printf("Invalid img (null).\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Printing img of row length %d and col length %d:\n", im->rows, im->cols);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<im->rows; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<im->cols; j++) {
            printf("%d ", im->pixels[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    // test variables to hold values returned by the functions
    img_t* test_im = NULL;
    img_t* null_im = NULL;
    img_t* test2_im = NULL;
    img_result_t test_result = IMG_OK;
    int val;
    
    printf("Creating test_im by calling 'img_create(10, 10)'\n");
    test_im = img_create(10, 10);
    if (test_im == NULL) {
        printf("test_im == NULL\n");
        return 1; //exit with a non-zero value
    }
    printf("test_im created successfully.\n\n");

    

    printf("Testing img_set.\n");
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<test_im->rows; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j<test_im->cols; j++) {
            if (img_set(test_im, i, j, (rand()%100)) != IMG_OK) {
                printf("Cannot set value at index %d\n", i);
                return 1; //exit with a non-zero value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do basic debugging. Which condition inside `img_set` is failing? use a debugger to step thru the code. `if(row <= empty)` and `if(col <= empty)` ask yourself what values of `row` and `col` are you calling the function with and thus why those error conditions might trigger? You can easily find that out with any basic amount of debugging. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You have `return val;` at the end of `img_set()`, but you're supposed to return `IMG_OK`.  You're not supposed to change anything until you know all is OK, but you set `im->rows` and `im->cols` from the position.  That probably means your image shrinks when you set the `row = 0` and `col = 0` pixel.

Comment: Also the function does `return val;` whilst you are checking `img_set(test_im, i, j, (rand()%100)) != IMG_OK`

Comment: I think that last comment is an answer, probably the answer. @kaylum Let me know if you want to make an answer and want me to delete mine.

Answer (score 1):

Your `img_set` function has 4 bugs.

1. You overwrite the `img_t` configuration of rows and cols
2. Your check for lower boundary is wrong
3. No check for upper boundary
4. Wrong return type when the value has been stored.

See comments.

```
img_result_t img_set(img_t* im, unsigned int row, unsigned int col, int val){
  
  if(im == NULL) return IMG_BADARRAY;

  im->rows = row;  <--- Changing im->rows and cols are wrong.
  im->cols = col;  <--- Once im is created you never want to change them
  
  unsigned int empty = 0;  <--- why ? zero is always lower boundary

  if(row <= empty){ <--- This makes index zero invalid
    return IMG_BADROW;
  }
  if(col <= empty){ <--- This makes index zero invalid
    return IMG_BADCOL;
  }

  // Here should check for upper boundary

  im->pixels[row][col] = val;
  return val; <-------- Wrong return type

}
```

Try like:

```
img_result_t img_set(img_t* im, unsigned int row, unsigned int col, int val)
{
  if(im == NULL) return IMG_BADARRAY;

  if(row < 0 || row >= im->rows) return IMG_BADROW;

  if(col < 0 || col >= im->cols) return IMG_BADCOL;

  im->pixels[row][col] = val;
  return IMG_OK;
}
```

Further you have a bug in the create function:

```
arr->pixels[i] = malloc(cols*sizeof(img_t));
                                    ^^^^^
                                    wrong type
```

Then I wonder why your set-function takes the value as `int` when you actually want to store `uint8_t`. It's not illegal but it's a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at the same conclusion as kaylum:

> the function does `return val;` whilst you are checking `img_set(test_im, i, j, (rand()%100)) != IMG_OK`

And reading through your code I interpret your API concept so that the solution is to simply change

```
return val;
```

to

```
return IMG_OK;
```

because that is the expected status return value from `img_result_t` in success case.